# Callback when clicking on "Uninstall app" from Device administrator screen android (7.0)..?

Tags: android, adb, device-policy-manager

In marshmallo and bellow , i was able to see "Active" and "cancel" button in Device administrator screen and i can get the callbacks
in onActivityResult() 0,-1 respectively.but in android nougat (7.0) one new field is added along with two buttons (i.e) "Uninstall app".while clicking on this ,app is getting terminated showing uninstall pop screen

so is there any way to catch the callback while clicking on "Uninstall app" button

```
**code for pushing deviceadmin activity**

    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mComponentName);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ADMIN_INTENT);
```

How we can solve this...?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There is a broadcast sent whenever an app is uninstalled, i think you can try that. `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED`

Comment: show code......

Comment: @Akshay 
i already tried with below actions:
action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART"  
    action android:name="android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE" 
    action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" 
                action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" .

Comment: @Manish please find the attached code